# What are the options to Capybara's have_selector?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I got this error in RSpec. Are there any docs for `have_selector` that explain each key in the options hash and what exactly it does?

```
invalid keys :content, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait
```

Answer (score 25):

capybara provides this method to rspec. [capybara's docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) don't make it easy to find the answer to your question, so let's follow the source:

`have_selector` is in `Capybara::RSpecMatchers`. It delegates to the nested class `HaveSelector`, which delegates to the method `assert_selector`.

`assert_selector` is in `Capybara::Node::Matchers`. (So is a method `has_selector?`, although that's not what rspec calls.) [`assert_selector`'s rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#assert_selector-instance_method) documents the `:count` option. It also says "It also accepts all options that Finders#all accepts, such as :text and :visible." Clicking through to [`Finders#all`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method) finally gets us to the documentation of all the options:

Options Hash (options):

- text (String, Regexp) — Only find elements which contain this text or match this regexp
- visible (Boolean) — Only find elements that are visible on the page. Setting this to false finds - invisible and visible elements.
- count (Integer) — Exact number of matches that are expected to be found
- maximum (Integer) — Maximum number of matches that are expected to be found
- minimum (Integer) — Minimum number of matches that are expected to be found
- between (Range) — Number of matches found must be within the given range
- exact (Boolean) — Control whether `is` expressions in the given XPath match exactly or partially

Comment: When providing an invalid option and running tests, Capybara outputs a list of valid options:
 
`:count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :id, :class, :visible, :exact, :exact_text, :match, :wait, :filter_set`