# How to test for a target="_blank" attribute with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I'm trying something which I thought would be simple.  I need to modify a link to have the target="_blank" attribute and I would like to have a test to confirm that it's actually on the page.  I've tried a ton of variations, the closest I can get is:

```
it { should have_link('change', href: 'url', target: '_blank') }
```

but that just throws an error saying that 'target:' is an invalid key.  Is there a way to test for this attribute?  Moreover, is there a general method for testing for HTML element attributes?  The information I've found isn't clear.

Using Capybara 2.1.0, Rails 4.0.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want, or test for any attribute value, using `have_selector` and the CSS selector syntax for specifying attribute values, like this:

```
it { should have_selector('a[href="url"][target="_blank"]') }
```

It can't be done with `have_link`, since `have_link`

- doesn't take any HTML attribute as an option (it takes [the options that `have_selector` takes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961636/what-are-the-options-to-capybaras-have-selector/23962139), plus `:href`), and
- doesn't let you specify the entire selector.

Comment: My friend, it's times like this that I wish SO had a "buy you a beer" button in addition to vote up and accepted answer.  This worked like a charm.  I'm still a TDD newbie and this will be amazingly helpful.